# JavaCC: customizing lexer error messages

Tags: java, javacc

According to the [JavaCC documentation](https://javacc.java.net/doc/apiroutines.html), if I want to customize the messages given by errors in the lexer:

> To customize error reporting by the lexer, the lexer class must be subclassed and this method [`LexicalError()` in `TokenMgrError`] redefined in the subclass. To help with creating your error reporting scheme, the following variables are available:

However, I see nothing about how to get the generated code to use that subclass, unlike with the `TOKEN_FACTORY` option.

On the other hand, looking in the `TokenMgrError` source, some comments indicate that the source file should be directly edited, rather than subclassed.  However, if I do that, the next time I change the `.jj` file and have Ant regenerate the parser and lexer code, I get this warning:

> Warning: TokenMgrError.java: File is obsolete.  Please rename or delete this file so that a new one can be generated for you.

So, how am I supposed to be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `TokenMgrError` if you want. There isn't a lot of downside to it.

If you subclass the token manager, then you can subclass `TokenMgrError` too. You just need to be sure to override all the routines that create `TokenMgrError`.  To get the parser to use your subclass, you just create the parser like this

```
MyParser parser = new MyParser( new MySubclassTokenManagr(...) ) ;
```

Comment: So the "`File is obsolete`" warning is spurious?  Is there any way to suppress that warning?

Comment: Yes, it's spurious.  I don't know of a way to suppress the warning.